# Round datediff and sum

Tags: sql, ms-access, rounding, datediff

I have start and stop in a Access db
ex.

```
2015-01-01 12:10:00 - 2015-01-01 13:23:00
2015-01-02 08:45:00 - 2015-01-02 17:56:00
2015-01-03 13:32:00 - 2015-01-03 14:44:00
```

I would like to loop them through and get the diff between the timestamps in hours and minutes, I would also like to get the diff rounded up to the nearest 30 minute
and for the grand final, the total sum of the rounded time´s

ex.

```
1h 13m (1h 30m)
9h 11m (9h 30m)
1h 12m (1h 30m)
Sum = 12h 30m
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Are you able to compute the diff?  (Hint: look up `DateDiff`)

Comment: 1h and 5 min is nearest to 1h or 1h and 30 m? What is the rule?

Comment: "rounded up to the nearest 30 minute" Your example output indicates you mean "rounded up to the _next_ 30 minute"

Answer (score 0):

Dates in Access are stored in fractional days.

If you wish to [round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) them to a particular unit (30 minutes in your case), then multiply by the 86400/1800, add this value - 1, truncate the result and divide by the value again to return a date rounded correctly.

This ignores the tie-breaking expected when the value is a fractional unit and may be ambiguous with non-decimal units like time and angles.

Answer (score 0):

Just this to get the datediff

```
<% 
fromDate = RecSet3("timestart")
toDate= RecSet3("timestop")
%>
<%response.write(DateDiff("n",fromDate,toDate)\60)%>tim
<%response.write(DateDiff("n",[fromDate],[toDate])mod 60)%>min
```

I would always round up to the nearest half hour